# jQuery Getting text instead of value from select, and check initial value on page load

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a multi-part form, and the last "tab" is a summary tab. I want to show the values selected/entered from previous tabs to show on this summary tab. So far, I managed to get everything working (with normal and number input boxes), but with the select options, the internal value is shown, and I need the text value. Simply replacing .val() with .text() does not seem to work, as I need the selected text, not all the text to show.

jQuery:

```
    $('.summarySelect').change(function(){
        var $selectedValue = $(this);
        $('.'+$selectedValue.attr('id')+'').html($selectedValue.val());
    });
```

html:

```
<select name="material" class="form-control summarySelect" id="id_material">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="NO">No</option>

  <option value="YES" selected="">Yes</option>

</select>
```

The actual summary:

```
Material:
<span class="id_material"></span>
```

In addition to some help with the select boxes, I'd like some advice how to also get/check the initial value, as in our form some options may be pre-selected and may not be changed by the user. If the user does not change this value they will not show up in the summary tab.

accompanying jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubjn8xfr/4/

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing, when selecting the drop down value ?

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/fd657ysx/

Comment: $(this).find(":selected").text(); to get the selected option

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, this is exactly the solution I needed.